# Floating img and p inside div

Tags: html, css

I am learning float property in CSS. But I have one doubt. I want that image and paragraph should float on left and right inside div.

I am not getting image and paragraph floated on left and right. Paragraph is starting just below the image. But I want that paragraph should be on right side on the div.

But when I reduced the content of the paragrah it is floating on right side. It is confusing for me.

Using

```
<p>This is simple text</p>
```

then it is floating on right side of container and if content of paragraph is large then it is not floating on right side.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

p {
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="challenges.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto, perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis inventore voluptates non ducimus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Reducing the content of paragraph then it is floating on right side and if I increase the content of paragraph then it is starting just below the image.

Why is it so?

Comment: Insert your image inside the p tag. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: `float` is a property to `float` an element within flow text. Similar to an image in a newspaper. `float` is **not** a property to align elements next to each other. That is a still-misused hack from 2012. For aligning elements next to each other you should use either **flexbox** or **grid**.

Comment: Floating elements "float" on the same line as long as there is room for them, past this point they go to the next line. This is the behavior you are seeing. For the image to "float" properly inside the text, you must remove `float: right;` from your `<p>` styles so that it can wrap around the image, try it and tell us if this is what you wanted

Comment: It's OK to learn every possible CSS property, but thanks to CSS flex and grid I don't remember the last time I had to resort to `float` and its quirks. Just saying. Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

`float: right` on the paragraph tag essentially made it not behave to the other floating inside the container

Remove the float property on the paragraph tag and increase the text content so that you can actually see the text wrap around down.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float - this has an interactive example you play around to see what's actually happening.

If you want to align elements, I would suggest using flexboxes or grid to achieve the desired result. Floating elements does have it's uses but it shouldn't be misused.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        div {
          border: 2px solid red;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        img {
          float: left;
          border: 2px solid blue;
        }

        p {
          border: 2px solid cyan;
        }

        div::after {
          content: "";
          display: block;
          clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <img src="challenges.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.rem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
          quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
          perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
          inventore voluptates non ducimus.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

With float, we can do something like this. You don't have to use floats on both of them. Only the image will do. Or I think on some fixed dimension. For example, the image in this case.

If we use float: right on the image ( the image has to be inside the paragraph  itself )

[image]

if we use float: left; on the image
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home Page</title>

    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      div {
        border: 2px solid red;
      }

      img {
        float: left;
        border: 2px solid blue;
      }

      p {
        border: 2px solid cyan;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      
      <p>
        <img
        src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1690622546167709696/bxoTgi48_400x400.jpg"
        width="250"
        height="250"
      />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
        quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
        perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
        inventore voluptates non ducimus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Float is not used anymore, to be honest. Flexbox and Grid have taken over all the layout techniques previously used. Here is how you can achieve the same using flexbox.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <img
        src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1690622546167709696/bxoTgi48_400x400.jpg"
        width="250"
        height="250"
      />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
        quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
        perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
        inventore voluptates non ducimus.
      </p>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
   display: flex;
}

div {
   border: 2px solid red;
}

img {
   border: 2px solid blue;
}

p {
   border: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

Comment: This is definetly not equivalent, with this layout the text doesn't wrap around the image like it does with `float` when the text is long enough. Your code basically creates 2 columns

Comment: Okay, if that's the case. You might have to just use float. Everything else will fall into place.

Comment: float is still used and there is no other property that allows to let flow-text flow around elements and as such float cannot be replaced. It's poor wording to state that float is not sued anymore. It is just not sued for aligning elements next to each other anymore.

Comment: You are right, Float can have its place. But the use case for it has decreased significantly after the emergence of flex and grid.

Answer (score -4):

To float img and paragraph tag inside div, img and P tag must have a width less than div. For example, in your case, when you increase content in P tag then p tag width increases as well. So try giving some fixed width like 300px etc to a paragraph p tag and it will work the way you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      div {
        border: 2px solid red;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      img {
        float: left;
        border: 2px solid blue;
      }
      p {
          width: 300px;
        float: right;
        border: 2px solid cyan;
      }
      div::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="challenges.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nesciunt
        quis rem autem cupiditate molestias reprehenderit quia iusto,
        perspiciatis repellendus ipsam esse voluptatum culpa labore omnis
        inventore voluptates non ducimus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to remove the float right from the p

Comment: If paragraph content fit inside single horizontal line then it will work. Otherwise it will start just below image to fit its entire content??

Comment: @Deepakkumarsoni yes

Comment: @TemaniAfif you didn't understand his question, he is learning float property, so he must use float property to get the desired output for both p and img tag.

Comment: @NimraKhan Yes I am just using float to get the result. R u Indian ??

Comment: @Deepakkumarsoni you can get the output by giving width to p tag. Seems like some people didn't find my answer useful. i might say that they just didn’t understand the question.

Comment: @Deepakkumarsoni make sure to accept the right answer if it solves your query.

Comment: ppl didn't find your answer useful not because they didn't understand the question. They downvoted because you used an outdated hack that should not be used in the first place. Instead of repeating the misused hack you should teach the proper ways!

Comment: @tacoshy The latest hacks are not necessary to use always, what solves the problem is what's important even if it's an old hack. it all depends on requirements and his requirement is using float. if people don’t understand this simple thing then that's their problem.

Comment: I agree. Learning about a feature means learning about both its uses and its limitations. It's those limitations that allow understanding of _why_ float is a poor choice for the OP's use case.

Comment: @Alohci Yeah, but that's the dev choice if he wants to do it with float then how can he do it. Also, i believe with all these comments he will get the idea that float is not a good choice but it's his place to choose whatever he wants.

Comment: The Thing is building UI on the web has evolved over the years from using float, using tables, and then to using Flex and Grid. So, people making software on this day should use the things which are already a good option. Stretching it is just wasting time and effort.

If the software is built on older tech, better to migrate if possible than be sorry later on.